# What is the meaning of *$'\n'*

Tags: zsh

There is a zsh widget like

```
down-line-or-select() {
    if [[ $RBUFFER == *$'\n'* ]]; then
    zle down-line
    else
    zle menu-select -w
    fi
}

zle -N down-line-or-select
bindkey $terminfo[kcud1] down-line-or-select
```

Here, I am not understanding the meaning of `*$'\n'*`. Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The test `[[ $variable == pattern ]]` tests whether the variable's value matches the given shell pattern.

The pattern, in this instance, is `*$'\n'*`.  The `$'\n'` part of the pattern denotes a literal newline character.  `$'...'` in general is an "ANSI C string", which means backslash-escaped sequences inside `$'...'` are interpreted as described by the C language standard, where `\n` is a newline, `\t` a tab character, etc.  The flanking `*`'s would match any prefix and suffix string.

In short, the shell pattern `*$'\n'*` would match any string that contains at least one newline character.  In other words, the test would be *true* for any multi-line string in `$RBUFFER`.

The test itself would also be valid, as written, in the `bash` shell.

Comment: what is the condition for single line string in right buffer?

Comment: @AhmadIsmail To test whether `$string` contains no newlines, use `[[ $string != *$'\n'* ]]`.  So it's the same test, but with `==` changed into `!=` to negate the test.